# Laravel redirect with session

Tags: php, laravel-5, session-cookies

I want to redirect a user with a session created in domain A to domain B, and the user should be logged in in domain B after he's redirected.

I have tried `redirect->withCookie()` method with a Laravel session generated via a cUrl operation, but in domain B it kicks me out to the login page.

Comment: How are domain A and domain B configured? Does the cookie show up in the session on domain B?

Comment: No `Cookies` get overwrite by Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `Cookies` like that to a different domain. Cookies are tagged to the domain, so one domain (Domain-B) can't read the cookies of another domain (Domain-A).

You need to pass some sort of opaque credentials to Domain-B from Domain-A to let Domain-B know that he/she is already logged in. So, then Domain-B will simply register the user as logged in an issue its own cookie-session.

You could pass some sort of single-use or time-limited `access token` in the query param when redirecting. You would need to make a call from the second domain (Domain-B) to the first domain (Domain-A) to verify the access token is still valid

Ideally, You could use a signed *JSON Web Token (JWT)* as an `access token`. using a **JWT** would let you skip a step of checking the token with the first domain (Domain-A). Refer to https://jwt.io for generating JWT.

There are more options, like `OAuth` but that might be overkill for this.

Comment: First, `Cookies` I am passing to Domain-B is generated on Domain-B via cUrl operation, so its related to Domain-B, I have checked it in domain parameter of the cookie by `var_dump($_COOKIES)`. And yes I know `JWT` and `oAuth` are the way to achieve this. But why `redirect->withCookie()` a default function from `Laravel` is not working?

Comment: @JayPandya, The scenario is when you go to Domain-A, a cookie tagged to Domain-A is generated and the same thing on Domain-B happens. So anything you do to cookies on Domain-A only affects the cookie tagged to Domain-A, not the one tagged to Domain-B.

And I looked into the documentation, `redirect()->withCookie()` is meant to add additional cookie key-value pairs on redirect. It doesn't attach the cookie to be retrieved on another domain. From documentation, `return response($content)->withCookie(cookie('name', 'value'));`

Comment: Upvote only for clarification on `redirect->withCookie()`. But as I mentioned in the above comment `Cookies` are created on Domain-B via `cURL` operation, so they are definitely not related to Domain-A. Anyways I have achieved it via `oAuth` approach. Thanks.